# Source of Air in pressurised doors

Tags: acs-pressurization

In pressure cabins, pressurisation is very important. To keep the pressurisation level balanced, rubber seals are used.
Now what is the source of the air used to maintain this level of pressurisation?

Comment: Are you asking about the pressurisation of the cabin in general or specifically about how pressurised air can be used inside the rubber seals?

Answer (score 3):

You will generally find two kinds of seals:

1. Retractable pressurized seals that run off pressurized bleed air, maybe tapped off the deicing system or the high pressure side of the air conditioning system, and extend out from grooves in the door frame when the handle is locked.  There will normally be a pressure reservoir tank that can sustain pressure to the door seal if the bleed source fails.
2. Passive seals that are like tubular gaskets around the door frame. There will be vent holes in the tube exposed to the cabin air side when the seal compressed with the door closed, that allows ambient cabin air to pressurize the seal relative to the outside.

Neither of these types of seals works perfectly and pressurized cabins normally leak a fair amount past the various seals and gaskets, and through rivet holes and skin joints, becoming leakier and leakier as the airplane ages.